# What is the expected difference in the gap of two polynomials in $Z_2[x_1, ..., x_n]$ when adding a randomly chosen variable $x_i, i \in [n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, finite-fields

I define the gap of a polynomial $f \in Z_2[x_1, ..., x_n]$ as

$gap(f) = |f^{-1}(0)| - |f^{-1}(1)|$.

I'm curious about the quantity $\mathbb{E}_i[|gap(f) - gap(f + x_i)|]$. I'm interested in this quantity expressed as a function of whatever properties of $f$ you find salient to its computation. Ones that would be particularly useful for me is $s$, the number of terms in the polynomial, $d$, the maximum number of variables included in a single term.

Comment: Do $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ also?

Comment: $x_i$ is one of the variables, its a syntactic modification to $f$. @lisyarus

Comment: I mean, do your variables also come from $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: When evaluated at a particular $x$, sure, otherwise it is simply a symbol which was one of the original $\{x_i \mid i \in [n]\}$.

Comment: I believe there is an interesting question buried in here, but need to clarify a few points. 1) In defining the gap are you essentially thinking of $f$ as a boolean function in $n$ variables or as a polynomial? I suspect the former, but like lisyarus I'm slightly uncertain about the domain. You see, polynomials are not functions per se. They do become functions if you declare a set of possible values. I suspect you want the vector of inputs $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ to range over all of $\Bbb{Z}_2^n$, but an extension field could also be a possibility.

Comment: Yeah, I'm interpreting the polynomial as a function mapping $Z_2^n \rightarrow Z_2$, I assumed that was the "default" interpretation.

Comment: 2) You define a quantity $\Bbb{E}_i[\cdots]$. It looks like this is to be an expected value. An expected value needs a random variable. What is the random variable here? Choice of the index $i$? Can't be, then you would not need the subscript $i$ in the end product. The polynomial $f$? That would make sense, but you need to specify the range of the space of polynomials.

Comment: I'm taking $i$ uniformly from $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$. I'm not quite sure why you think I need $i$ in the end product?

Comment: Ok, so for you, for example $x_1^2-x_1$ can be equated with $0$. When restricted to $\Bbb{Z}_2$ they give rise to the same function, but as polynomials they are distinct (one has degree two but the other is constant).

Comment: Because you use the notation $\Bbb{E}_i$. I may have misunderstood, but to me that implies that there are $n$ distinct expected values. One for the random variable $gap(f)-gap(f+x_1)$ another for the random variable $gap(f)-gap(f+x_2)$ et cetera. Except that then the randomness would need to come from the choice of $f$ which is incompatible with the rest of the text.

Comment: Yes, that is true. To clarify why this is consistent with wanting the result to be a function of $s$, I'm hoping for an upper bound of something like $O(log(s))^C$ for some unknown parameter on the polynomial $C$. With respect to $\mathbb{E}_i$ notation, I just meant $i$ is the random variable we're taking the expectation over.

Comment: Anyway, I suspect that some interesting cases may come out from the study of Reed-Muller codes and/or bent functions. I need to wrap my head around this :-)

Comment: I'll look into those things in the morning! Thank you so much for your interest and clarification. Feel free to edit the question to fit the standards around here, I'm just popping in from cstheory cause if they weren't able (or willing) to solve my cs version of this when I asked, I doubt they'll be able to figure out the math version.

Comment: I guess your notation is fine, I just brought in my own hangups and misunderstood. I check out what happens, when $f$ is a bent function. Hmm. Looks like the expected value will then be zero. Need something else :-)